# Google app engine sample app throwing 503

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have setup Google app engine's sample android from [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/getting_started)

when I type something into the EditText and press Send Button, nothing happens for a while and throws the following error

```
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741): error: 
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741): {
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):   "code": 503,
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):   "errors": [
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):     {
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):       "domain": "global",
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):       "message": "",
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):       "reason": "backendError"
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):     }
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):   ],
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):   "message": ""
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741): }
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:314)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1060)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackend.insert(CloudBackend.java:111)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync.access$0(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:87)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
06-10 18:47:49.109: I/CloudBackend(28741):  at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:428)
```

It is very annoying that the message is "" !
P.S: I am new to Google app engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for this.

It seems like there is a bug in app engine that every time when your app generates a new version of itself by you redeploying it or so, it forgets to make the latest deployment as default under app engine console.
Follow the steps to make it default:

1. go to [appengine console](https://appengine.google.com/)
2. Open your project
3. On the left hand side, open up Main -> Versions
4. Make the most latest version as default by clicking the radio button beside it.

**That's it I hope**

Answer (score 3):

It could probably a data conversion error. The server is expecting values in one format and client is sending in some other format (parsing layer issue in google cloud endpoint). 
I would highly suggest you to make use of google's api explorer tool to verify first that your server side interface is working without any problem. 
Then you should move on find out any problems with client side.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I pass '1999' to my `java.util.Date` variable

Comment: Quite interesting why this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you manually created the "datastore-indexes.xml" file (assuming it's in bad form) under WEB-INF, you will receive this error.

I deleted mine and the problem was fixed....

Comment: not sure who voted down this answer, but this situation happened to me and I was just providing my experience.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the perfect fix.

Log on to the app engine. Click on Instances on the left hand side.
At the right bottom , you will see an option as "Shutdown"

Click on Shutdown. (Shutdown is not just shutdown. Its a restart).

The instance gets started in 10-12 seconds. Note : During these 10-12 seconds , the app engine is not accessible. So, if your app is live , your cloud will not work for these 10-12 seconds.

Refresh the page after 10 seconds and make sure you see the Shutdown option . This means your instance is restarted.

Now , retry and it will work. Send me email to jscript12@gmail.com if you still have questions

Comment: did that, and instance is gone, no shutdown button visible or instance at all, even after 5 minutes...

Comment: It will not restart automatically. It will wait for an API call to wake up and create a container (instance) to run your back end. Good call Jay, gae crapped out on me and this fixed it!